# Передача массива объектов в конструктор как аргументы

Tags: java, spring

Всем привет.
Допустим мы имеем

```
List<Object[]> argList
```

И имеем класс с данным конструктором:

```
public myClass(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3){
  this.arg1 = arg1;
  this.arg2 = arg2;
  this.arg3 = arg3;
}
```

Как передать в конструктор данные из листа?

Comment: Есть ли какой-то смысл изначально в этом листе? Или почему нельзя этот же лист и передать и оттуда взять значения если конкретное их количество заранее известно?  Что именно это за аругменты? В чём идея и задача?

Comment: у вас код неправильный, String с большой буквы должен быть, как и конструктор

Comment: Я написал исправленный вариант, можете запустить и проверить. Вы такой случай рассматривали?

Comment: @SergeyZh. да, это рабочий вариант, но это не совсем то что я бы хотел.
Можно ли сделать чтобы я параметром отсылал класс, он находил конструктор и делал подстановку

Comment: @ДжейкМорган Не понял вопроса, что именно вы хотите сделать? Куда параметром, какой класс, какой конструктор и какая подстановка?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю зачем вам это, задание мягко говоря странное, но если уж требуется, то можно так:

```
    List<Object[]> argList = new ArrayList<>();
    argList.add(new Object[]{1,2,3});
    MyClass someObject = new MyClass((String) argList.get(0)[0], (String) argList.get(0)[1], (String) argList.get(0)[2]);
```

Но не надо так делать в реальном рабочем коде!

И если уж на то пошло, то и конструктор класса у вас написан неправильно (java - регистрозависимый язык), там нет string, а есть String.
Так что за одно и исправленный вариант класса прикреплю:

```
class MyClass {
String arg1;
String arg2;
String arg3;

public MyClass(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3){
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
    this.arg3 = arg3;
}
```

}